# Does interference at a metal surface increase transmittance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I read pdf's on google that we can increase transmittance through interference,is it true.If two waves are overlapping each other constantly as they are travelling they are also interfering constantly too,does this increase transmittance?.is there any other way to increase transmittance through metals even for thick films?

Comment: Can you link to the material you've read?

Comment: [link](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep29195)

Comment: Seems that the basic idea behind the approach is revealed in the 2nd sentence of the abstract: "In a metallic film coated with a thin semiconductor film, both transmission and absorption are simultaneously enhanced as a result of dramatically reduced reflection." So it sounds like the thin semiconductor film is essentially an anti-reflection coating for the metal film.

Comment: But there are other pdf's that doesn't use thin semiconductor coating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. This strategy relies on no patterned nanostructures.

> In this paper, we demonstrate that optical transmission can be significantly enhanced relying on this strong interference dominated by interface phase shift in planar metal/semiconductor double-layered films. While the absorption is significantly boosted, the transmission is also remarkably augmented at slightly red-shifted wavelength. Metallic films with simultaneous superior electrical conductivity and high optical transmissivity are highly desirable in many energy-harvesting optoelectronic devices such as liquid-crystal displays, solar cells, light-emitting diodes26,27. Since no patterned nanostructure is required in this scheme, this method presents the virtue of large-area and lithography-free fabrication as well as design flexibility; besides, the strong interference dominated by interface phase shift reduces the film thickness required for creating resonances and results into a broadband operation and high angular tolerance. This scheme opens an extraordinary transmission window for a seamless metallic layer without any assistance of patterned nanostructures and thus may find potential applications in energy-harvesting applications such as thin-film photovoltaics and surface photocatalysis.

Please see the citation here:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4940859/